# Trying to get loading image to show when calling an AJAX function -- works great in Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-browser, loading

I have this code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#loading').hide().ajaxStart(function() {
            $(this).show();
         }).ajaxStop(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
});
</script>
```

When I initially perform an action that an AJAX call is being made, the loading image displays and starts rotating but in that AJAX call, I call multiple other AJAX calls and the loading image exhbits different behavior depending on the browser.

**Firefox** = Works as intended. When I perform action that executes AJAX, it displays loading image until AJAX call is completed.

**Google Chrome** = Starts to work, the loading image loads but as soon as other AJAX calls are executed (from the initial one, in the success phase), the loading image freezes and doesn't animate again.

**IE9 / Safari** = Simply does not render the loading image.

I want the other browsers to work it just like Firefox. Any ideas why this may be happening?

Comment: For loops and synchronous calls can lock up the rendering.

Comment: Not sure if it matters too much, I'm still trying to wrap my head on how the asynchronous works but my AJAX calls have "async: false" because some rely on the other and I may need them to execute in a particular order.

Comment: that is a bad idea "async: false" was depreciated. I would suggest you take a different approach to this all together. I would show your load image each time an ajax call is made if it is not already showing. Then in the success of the ajax, hide it. If you need your ajax to execute in a specific order then you should queue your ajax calls on the document and then in each success handler call the next method of the queue. Then as the last entry in the queue you would hide the loading image.

Comment: Making synch calls means the browser will lock up. Firefox happens to someone win the race condition to show the loading graphic, the other browsers are not winning the race.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yes, the issue is certainly with async : false, thanks everyone.